# Is claim based authorization is replacing role based authorization in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, roles, claims-based-identity

I have used role based authorization in many ASP.NET 4.x projects. But, now in ASP.NET Core, I'm feeling that it is going to be retired in favour of claims or other new methods of authorization in ASP.NET Core such as resource based or policy based authorization.

Am I correct? If yes, how this transition is going to happen? Does Microsoft has a formal recommendation for this?

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is still supported. While the general recommendation would be to use policies as they are more powerful, you can still use roles just fine.